# How to add child element to XElement as a decoded string?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I want to make pass this test. What should I use instead of Add method?

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddContentWithoutEncoding()
{
   var element = new XElement("Parent");

   element.Add("<Son>5</Son>");

   Assert.IsTrue(element.ToString() == "<Parent><Son>5</Son></Parent>");
}
```

With the current approach `element.ToString() = "<Parent>&lt;Son&gt;5&lt;/Son&gt;</Parent>"` that's obviously  encoding tag content.

I have a big constant string with tags which I need to add to XElement (because I use it feurther). And want to use some clever solution than `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` - just add the decoded string rather than decode the whole result after adding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try,

```
var element = new XElement("Parent");
foreach(string xml in list)
    element.Add(XElement.Parse(xml));
```

You probably also want in your Assert...

```
Assert.IsTrue(element.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting) == ...
```

Comment: :) it's obviously. I don't want to use this approach because I need to add a bulk of constant tags (~100) and I don't want to create XElement for all of them.

Comment: Give an example of your strings/array so that we have something to work from.

Comment: If you have a list/array of string tags, I adjusted my answer that may work for you.

Comment: Imagine string like "<Tag1/><Tag2>40</Tag2><Tag3><Tag4>...<Son56>345<Son56> ...<Tag4></3Tag>....<Tag100>....</Tag100>" with different levels of inheritance

Comment: I have just a string with elements, not elements.

Comment: @BurundukXP XElement.Parse is the best way to convert the string to an XElement represention so that you can add it to an existing XElement, convert it to a string, and read it in as a set of XElements later.  You can add strings with markup to elements using element.WriteCData, but when you parse it later, it will be read in as element content, and not be converted to XElements.

Comment: @MonroeThomas ok. thanks, I'm a bit worried the speed of this approach - will test it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an `XElement.Parse` and then add like this:

```
var element = new XElement("Parent");

element.Add(XElement.Parse("<Sone>5</Sone>"));

Console.WriteLine(element.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
```

This gives me the output you are looking for.

Comment: whether is Parse better than decoding the result?

Comment: @ChuckSavage  add child tag as in the question and than decode the result - HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(element.ToString())